# Spark Error: Error downloading resource: SSL connect error

Tags: apache-spark, nexus, mesos

I am attempting to run a job on a Spark cluster setup in Mesos. I can run a job if I copy the jar to the server and then use a `file:` URL, but I cannot get spark to download a jar using `https:`. Every time I do get the error below in the stderr file.

```
I0226 00:11:05.618361 22652 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I0226 00:11:05.618552 22652 fetcher.cpp:409] Fetcher Info: ...
I0226 00:11:05.619721 22652 fetcher.cpp:364] Fetching URI 'https://jenkins.company.com/nexus/...
I0226 00:11:05.619738 22652 fetcher.cpp:238] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
I0226 00:11:05.619751 22652 fetcher.cpp:176] Fetching URI 'https://jenkins.company.com/nexus/...
I0226 00:11:05.619762 22652 fetcher.cpp:126] Downloading resource from 'https://jenkins.company.com/nexus/...
Failed to fetch 'https://jenkins.company.com/nexus/... ': Error downloading resource: SSL connect error
Failed to synchronize with slave (it's probably exited)
```

I am able to use `wget` to download the jar from the specified URL. I have also verified that the JDK on the server has the correct certificate for the nexus server where I am attempting to download the jar from.

I am new to Spark and Mesos and any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify you private Nexus repository with the `--repository` flag on application start?

I personally never use encryption together with Spark, but from the docs it seems to be possible/necessary to configure it within Spark. I guess just for the SDKs is not enough.

See

- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#encryption